# VB macros in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i am new to working with macros and writing macros in excel. CAn someone point me to some tutorials/examples which will help me understand and write macros for writing and editing excel documents.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of examples on the [Chip Pearson site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/topic.aspx) although some may be a bit advanced

Answer (score 0):

I found it very useful some time ago: [Here](http://www.lynda.com/Excel-2010-tutorials/macros-in-depth/74463-2.html?srchtrk=index:2%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq%3avba%0Apage:1%0As%3arelevance%0Asa%3atrue%0Aproducttypeid:2%0Ameta_software_facet%3aExcel)

When I went over it; I had some undestanding. But in order to start coding vba you need to get some project going. 
When you work on, just ask questions / google your needs.
For example "excel vba copy cell to another cell" "excel vba open workbook" "excel vba activate worksheet" and so on. Internet is full of examples and you just have to use it. You can start coding vba in no time.

Good luck!